# append don't work with lambda and map. How to add new element in list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to make a list of lists with map and lambda in Python.
I have this construction, but append doesn't work.

```py
my_list = [[0, 1], [0, 1]]
my_list = list(map(lambda x: x.append(1), my_list))
```

I expect the result to be something like this:

```py
[[0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1]]
```

I tried this:

```
list(map(lambda x: [x[0], x[1], 1], my_list))
```

This is works (result is `[(0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 1)]`), but I actually want to use something like append, because it depends on dimension of list.

If I have input list like

```py
my_list = [[0, 1], 0]
```

it doesn't work.

Comment: The second one doesn't actually work. I get `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable`.

Comment: What's your expected output for `my_list=[[0,1],0]`? Please [edit] to clarify. See [ask] if you want more tips.

Comment: **don't use `map` for side-effects**. Just use a regular for-loop.

Comment: i expect my_list=[   [0,1,1],   [0,1]   ]

Comment: So, your code actually works, but you mutate the original list in-place, but then assign the result of `list(map(...))` to the same variable, discarding that old list. But again, **don't use `map` for side-effects**

Comment: @Alexander Please [edit] to include that

Comment: @juanpa Sorry, which part works? For the first snippet, I get `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append'`

Comment: list(map(lambda x: [x[0],x[1],1], my_list)) - works

Comment: @wjandrea right, the code doesnt' work at all, I assumed the op had something like `[[1], [0]]`

Comment: this is work my_list=[[0,1],[0,1]]
my_list=list(map(lambda x: (x[0],x[1],[1]), my_list)) i have corrected source list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using map and lambda you can do:

```py
my_list = [[0, 1], [0, 1]]
my_list = list(map(lambda x: x + [1], my_list))
print(my_list)
```

Output:

```py
[[0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1]]
```

---

A Comprehension also works:

```py
my_list = [[0, 1], [0, 1]]
my_list = [x + [1] for x in my_list]
print(my_list)
```

Output:

```py
[[0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1]]
```

---

Edit: Your second sample input implies the potential for non-list elements.

Here's one way to handle that case:

```py
my_list = [[0, 1], 0]
my_list = [(x if isinstance(x, list) else [x]) + [1] for x in my_list]
print(my_list)
```

Output:

```py
[[0, 1, 1], [0, 1]]
```